# What web technologies and frameworks are used for kayak.com?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web-frameworks

As a matter of curiosity, what web technologies and frameworks are powering kayak.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:
http://www.kayak.com/tech

Comment: " **served up by Apache, Tomcat, Java, with Perl operational glue, all running on Linux**. We use MySQL when we need to do database things. We use memcached to keep the database from getting crushed"